# Mixed content issue - Google managed SSL and Web Server SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I'm currently using a Google managed SSL with a bitnami WordPress. The website has mixed content issue. The media library is still using `http://`

Since I'm using Google mananged SSL, I can't set up a SSL(Let'sEncrypt) on the server because the domain is resolved to the load balancer's IP.

It will break the site if I change

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );    
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

to

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );
```

What can I do here to resolve the mixed content issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that WordPress is not detecting that users connected to the load balancer using HTTPS. You have configured the load balancer to connect to your backend using `http`, which is recommended, but WordPress does not know that.

Add the following to `wp-config.php`. Then you can start using `https` for your WordPress configuration.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']))
{
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
    {
           $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    }
}
```

Note: This will fix mixed content issues except those that were caused by the above configuration issue.

Comment: Just in case others are facing the same issue, I would like to highlight that the solution works with WordPress but not bitnami WordPress.